# Is $\zeta$ a solution to the Einstein field equations?

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

Consider a Lorentzian manifold $(\zeta,g)$ with metric $g=\frac{dudv}{uv}-\frac{dr^2}{r^2}-\frac{dw^2}{w^2}.$

Clearly $\zeta$ is diffeomorphic to Minkowski space, $\Bbb R^{3,1}.$ $\zeta$ also has zero curvature like Minkowski space.

> Is $\zeta$ a solution to the Einstein field equations?

I know that Lorentzian manifolds are solutions to the Einstein field equations. But I'm wondering if $\zeta$ would still be a solution to the equations or rather some variant of the equations.

Comment: I assume you’re restricting to $u, v,w,r>0$? If so, your space *is* Minkowski space but written in coordinates different from the standard ones. Separately, you are right. Any space with a Lorentzian metric with zero curvature is a solution to the vacuum Einstein equations.

Comment: Where there is no curvature of space time there is no gravity, a manifold without metric giving some curvatures is a solution for a flat space

Comment: I still don't really understand why when you change coordinates, the Einstein field equations don't change to reflect the new coordinates

Comment: for example, Laplace equation, $\nabla^2 f =0,$ changes form and the solutions change when you change coordinates

Comment: i bookmarked :)

Comment: @Deane yes but would the vacuum Einstein equations be written the same way in this case?

Comment: @geocalc33, the Ricci curvature $R$  tensor and scalar curvature function $S$ are defined on any manifold with a Lorentzian metric $g$, no matter what coordinates are used. Einstein's vacuum equations are always $$R - \frac{1}{2}Sg.$$ If you have a formula for the metric $g$ with respect to some set of coordinates, then you can calculate formulas for the Ricci and scalar curvatures. From this, you can check whether the metric satisfies Einstein's vacuum equations.